# How to add another item to carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

So I'm trying to add another item to this carousel that I found on codepen, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

The point of the carousel is to show a bunch of books that you can browse through. If anyone could help me by adding one or two book items and perhaps letting me know how you did it? I'd really appreciate that!

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div class="slider">
        <input type="radio" name="testimonial" id="t-1">
        <input type="radio" name="testimonial" id="t-2">
        <input type="radio" name="testimonial" id="t-3" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="testimonial" id="t-4">
        <input type="radio" name="testimonial" id="t-5">
        <div class="testimonials">
            <label class="item" for="t-1">
                <img src="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/s/arva.png">
        <a href="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/unraveling-arva"></a>
            </label>
            <label class="item" for="t-2">
                 <img src="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/s/glassboys.jpg">
        <a href="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/glass-boys"></a>       
            </label>
            <label class="item" for="t-3">
        <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/60a8369fd20de56185381ba2/1621638067741-015L8NZNOQRZ2INSZFBJ/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kN7XjnOeyBG_pIHGk9Gs1lBZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZUJFbgE-7XRK3dMEBRBhUpwUJhz1iDgCkcnkJtht8qU86z6JQqWZLopbxZKVqc2vInNKk6_CE_jsazf_GmrMjp4/SubstituteCoverFinal.jpg?format=300w" alt="picture">
        <a href="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/thesubstitute"></a>
            
            </label>
            <label class="item" for="t-4">
        <img src="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/s/widowtree.jpg">
            <a href="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/the-widow-tree"></a>
            </label>
            <label class="item" for="t-5">
        <img src="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/s/thaw.png">
        <a href="https://www.nicolelundrigan.com/thaw"></a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dots">
            <label for="t-1"></label>
            <label for="t-2"></label>
            <label for="t-3"></label>
            <label for="t-4"></label>
            <label for="t-5"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.slider-wrapper {
        body {
            margin: 0;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        .slider {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .slider input {
            display: none;
        }
        .testimonials {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: relative;
            min-height: 450px;
            perspective: 1000px;
         //   overflow: hidden;
        }
        .testimonials .item {
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: grey;
           // padding: 30px;
            width: 250px;
          height: 400px;
            text-align: center;
            transition: transform 0.4s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            user-select: none;
            cursor: pointer;
          
          a {
            height: 400px;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 250px;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            opacity: 0.3;
          }
        }
        .testimonials .item img {
            width: 100px;
          //  border-radius: 50%;
           // border: 13px solid #3B344D;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          filter: brightness(0.8);
         transition: filter 0.4s;

        }

  
        .testimonials .item p {
            color: #ddd;
        }
        .testimonials .item h2 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .dots {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .dots label {
            display: block;
            height: 5px;
            width: 5px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: salmon;
            margin: 7px;
            transition: transform 0.2s, color 0.2s;
        }

        /* First */
        #t-1:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-1"] {
            transform: scale(2);
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-2"] {
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-1"] {
            z-index: 4;
           a {display: block; }
          img {filter: none;}
           box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-2"] {
            transform: translateX(200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(-15deg);
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-3"] {
            transform: translateX(400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(-25deg);
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-4"] {
            transform: translateX(600px) translateZ(-270px) rotateY(-35deg);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #t-1:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-5"] {
            transform: translateX(800px) translateZ(-360px) rotateY(-45deg);
        }

        /* Second */
        #t-2:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-1"] {
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-2"] {
            transform: scale(2);
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-3"] {
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-1"] {
            transform: translateX(-200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(15deg);
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-2"] {
            z-index: 3;
           a {display: block; }
          img {filter: none;}
           box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-3"] {
            transform: translateX(200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(-15deg);
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-4"] {
            transform: translateX(400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(-25deg);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #t-2:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-5"] {
            transform: translateX(600px) translateZ(-270px) rotateY(-35deg);
        }

      /* Third */
      #t-3:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-2"] {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-3"] {
          transform: scale(2);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-4"] {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-1"] {
          transform: translateX(-400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(25deg);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-2"] {
          transform: translateX(-200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(15deg);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-3"] {
          z-index: 3;
        a {display: block; }
        img {filter: none;}
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
      }
      #t-3:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-4"] {
          transform: translateX(200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(-15deg);
          z-index: 2;
      }
  
  #t-3:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-5"] {
    transform: translateX(400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(-25deg);
}
      /* Fourth */
      #t-4:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-3"] {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-4"] {
          transform: scale(2);
       //   background-color: #fff;
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-5"] {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-1"] {
          transform: translateX(-600px) translateZ(-270px) rotateY(35deg);
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-2"] {
          transform: translateX(-400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(25deg);
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-3"] {
          transform: translateX(-200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(15deg);
          z-index: 2;
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-4"] {
          z-index: 3;
         a {display: block; }
        img {filter: none;}
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
        
      }
      #t-4:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-5"] {
          transform: translateX(200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(-15deg);
      }

      /* Fifth */
      #t-5:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-4"] {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .dots label[for="t-5"] {
          transform: scale(2);
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-1"] {
          transform: translateX(-800px) translateZ(-360px) rotateY(45deg);
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-2"] {
          transform: translateX(-600px) translateZ(-270px) rotateY(35deg);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-3"] {
          transform: translateX(-400px) translateZ(-180px) rotateY(25deg);
          z-index: 2;
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-4"] {
          transform: translateX(-200px) translateZ(-90px) rotateY(15deg);
          z-index: 3;
      }
      #t-5:checked ~ .testimonials label[for="t-5"] {
          z-index: 4;
         a {display: block; }
        img {filter: none;}
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
      }
}
```

Comment: how many you want?

Comment: @Crystal   I already have five, I would like six if that's possible.

Comment: @Crystal Hey, have you been able figure it out?

Comment: can you put your js i just want to make sure this all works

Comment: @Crystal Hi, there's no JS with this one. It's just HTML and CSS.

Comment: Im running it, It doesnt work on my end so ill look more on it. If I can't figured it out ill just send you a pen that you can use.

Comment: did you figured this out. I have another option for you that I made. let me know

Comment: @Crystal I haven't figured it out yet and have been working on the other parts of the website. I'd love to see the option you made for me, thank you! :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/CrystalRcodes/pen/qBpJJjN heres some simple one. we can put more animation on it. but i cant view your code.